# Passing Dictionay Object from javascript to c#

Tags: c#, javascript, dictionary, durandal

I work in durandal project and need to pass a parameter that its type is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>`.

I wanted to send:

```
{ name:'Ruvi', id:'324324', isChild:false }
```

But I cannot do it, because the properties names are dynamic (name, id, isChild), I accept them in array.
like:

```
['name', 'id', 'isChild']
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructing a JavaScript object with properties from an array:

```
var props = ['name', 'id', 'isChild'];

var obj = {};
var i = props.length;
while (i--) {
  obj[props[i]] = somehowGetValue(props[i]);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```